# Variadic template extractions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I faced something I cannot understand nor find a way to work around properly. What I am trying to achieve looks relatively simple: I want to compare some data.

Best way to describe would be a line of code:

```
std::tuple<const char *, int, const char *, int> my_data =
    std::make_tuple("hello", 13, "world", 37);
// Now I want to compare my_data againt some known value.
assert(Test::entry(my_data, "hello", 13, "world", 37));
```

I am using a tuple for the sake of the example. I my case, those data comes from a message object and are extracted using `operator>>`. However, this is not related to the problem.

Here is a minimalist code to illustrate the problem.

```
#include <cstring>
using MyTuple = std::tuple<const char *, int, const char *, int>;

namespace Test
{

  // called when we are done                                                                                                                                                                 
  bool extract(MyTuple source)
  {
    return true;
  }

  template<typename T,
           typename ...Content>
  bool extract(MyTuple source, T data, Content... content)
  {
    if (std::is_same<const char *, T>::value)
      assert(0); // why ? :(                                                                                                                                                                 
    std::cout << "Generic: " << data << std::endl;
    return extract(source, content...);
  }

  template<typename ...Content>
  bool extract(MyTuple source, const char *str, Content... content)
  {
    std::cout << "Overloaded: " << str << std::endl;
    return extract(source, content...);
  }

  template<typename ...Content>
  bool entry(const std::tuple<const char *, int, const char *, int> &data,
             Content... content)
  {
    return extract(data, content...);
  }

};
```

I would normaly perform comparaison in the `extract()` functions, but for keeping the example simple, I removed them.

What I want to achieve is proper dispatching. Based on the example it is my understanding that call order should be:

1. Overloaded for `const char *`
2. Generic
3. Overload for `const char *`
4. Generic

However, the output of this test program is:

1. Overloaded: hello
2. Generic: 13
3. `Assertion failed`. The `std::is_same` test trigger the `assert`.

What I discovered was that the `const char *` overload will not be called after the generic overload has been call once.

I am missing something?

EDIT: Also not that if I define the `const char *` overload before the generic function, this wont even compile.

Comment: It's a bit silly to use `std::make_tuple` when you already know the type of tuple you want - the whole point of `make_tuple` is to deduce the tuple type from the types of the initializers. You may as well simply use `std::tuple<const char *, int, const char *, int> my_data{"hello", 13, "world", 37};`

Comment: @Casey Yeah this was only for illustrating my problem. My data source is a socket from which I extract stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Also note that if I define the `const char *` overload before the generic function, this wont even compile.*

A declaration should suffice:

```
template <typename... Content>
bool extract(MyTuple source, const char *str, Content... content); // <- here

template <typename T, typename... Content>
bool extract(MyTuple source, T data, Content... content)
{
    std::cout << "Generic: " << data << std::endl;
    return extract(source, content...);
}

template <typename... Content>
bool extract(MyTuple source, const char *str, Content... content)
{
    std::cout << "Overloaded: " << str << std::endl;
    return extract(source, content...);
}
```

> *Why?*

The overload taking `const char*` is not visible during this particular *name lookup* without prior declaration. Some of the exceptions to this can be found in [comments below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021692/variadic-template-extractions/27022226#comment42578486_27022226).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It all makes sense now. This also probably explain why trying to hide the function with `std::enable_if` caused compile time error, as the other one wasn't available.

Comment: The reason the `const char *` overload can't be found is that it's neither found by unqualified lookup (using the definition context) nor available by ADL. If `MyTuple` had named a type in the `Test` namespace, ADL using the instantiation context would have allowed the `const char *` overload to be found even without a prior declaration.

Comment: @T.C. I don't think I understand. Do you mean like `typedef`ing `MyTuple` inside the `Test` namespace? Could you provide an example please?